# creating a tinted and shaded edge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, depth

I`m new to illustrator and want to create a tinted and shaded edges from the [google material design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons).

[image]
[image]

The above is the sample, the blue colors are the tinted edges, which I want to create I was able to create a square with border radius but not with this tinted edges.

**Current result:**

[image]

Comment: What you do to try and create the shadows? What resources have you looked at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For Illustrator

The easiest way to accomplish this for any shape is to add a **new Fill** via the **Appearance Panel**, highlight that new fill and choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` from the menu. Add a little bit of vertical offset and you should be set.

[image]

(There are actually a few different ways to transform fills in Illustrator to get this effect, this is among the easiest.)

## For Photoshop

The theory is the same... duplicate shape, change fill color, offset slightly from the original shape. However, Photoshop doesn't have the Appearance panel so you need to use an additional *layer* for the offset color under the original layer, that's all.

Comment: this is a great answer. just in case anyone wants to do this for something online: a simple css solution like `box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px 0px blue` should do the trick

Comment: Thx for the advice.